# Importing Excel and Translation then Exporting Excel again

Tags: python, excel, attributeerror, google-translate

I'd like to translate with a `goolge translator` from `excel` file and then export to `excel` again.
But I got an error :

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

```
import pandas as pd
from google_trans_new import google_translator

df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
print(df)

translator = google_translator()
translate_text = translator.translate(df,lang_tgt='fr')
print(translate_text)

translate_text.to_excel('new_data.xlsx')
```

**below is printed result**

```
      Hi
0  Hello

salut  0 bonjour
```

**`data.xlsx` is like this**

[image]

Comment: have you printed the variable translae_text to see what format it is in?

Comment: That tells me it is no longer in a a dataframe, but a string. You would have to convert the string back into a dataframe

Comment: @goalie1998 I added printed results. and I will try to convert it into a dataframe according to your advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from google_trans_new import google_translator

text = ','.join(pd.read_excel('demo.xlsx',header=None)[0].values)
translated_text = translator.translate(text,lang_tgt='fr')
pd.DataFrame(translated_text.split(',')).to_excel('new_data.xlsx',header=False,index=False)
```

The above code does following 3 steps:

1. Read the values from a excel file & make it a string of words with comma separators.
2. Pass that string to the translator.
3. Translated text is again splitted on comma and converted to a dataframe to store it in a excel file.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried your code. It works well. But when sentence is long (ex) Thank you) the sentences are broken into separate lines.(first row -> Thank, second row -> you). Can you get them in one row?

Comment: Changed the delimiter to comma in both 1st and 3rd step and it will work for all the long sentences then. If you want the output that gives correct output for comma as well, then use any special character that is not in your sentence.

Comment: It really works well. That is what I exactly wanted. I really appreciate your help! Thank you!!

Comment: I am sorry but I have 1 more question. Actually I have like 500 rows to translate but when I executed this code it said "Warning  Can only detect less than 5000 characters". Can you please advise for this problem?